# Changing values of static class variables in a nested loop

Tags: java, loops, object, static, instance

I'm having an issue with changing the values of a class variable within nested loops - I can't figure out why. I'm guessing it's because the variable is **static**. But it's a static method and because it's used for listing a User in a system from a file, it has to be static (I'm calling it from main method to read file to TreeMaps). Is it not possible to rewrite a static class variable from within a method? If it's possible - what the heck am I doing wrong?

```
public class Loan{

protected int noOfLoans;
protected int noOfReturns;
protected User user=new User();
protected static Book book= new Book();
protected Map <Integer, Book> currentLoans=new TreeMap <Integer, Book>();
protected Map <Integer, Book> returned=new TreeMap <Integer, Book>();   
protected static Map<Integer, Loan> loanList=new TreeMap<Integer, Loan>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    readLoans();
}

public static void readLoans(){
    loanList.clear();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("loans.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line = null;
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (line!=null) {
        String[] splitOut=line.split("-");
        String[] loan_User=splitOut[0].split(",");
        String[] loan_CurrentLoans=splitOut[2].split(",");
        String[] loan_Returned=splitOut[4].split(",");
        Loan loan = new Loan();
        loan.user.setFirstName(loan_User[0]);
        loan.user.setSurname(loan_User[1]);
        loan.user.setPersonalID(loan_User[2]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(splitOut[1]); i++) {
            book.setName(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)]);
            book.setAuthorFirstname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+1]);
            book.setAuthorSurname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+2]);
            book.setISBN(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+3]);
            loan.currentLoans.put(i, book);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(splitOut[3]); i++) {
            book.setName(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)]);
            book.setAuthorFirstname(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)+1]);
            book.setAuthorSurname(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)+2]);
            book.setISBN(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)+3]);
            loan.returned.put(i, book);
        }
        loan.setNoOfLoans(Integer.parseInt(splitOut[1]));
        loan.setNoOfReturns(Integer.parseInt(splitOut[3]));
        loanList.put(loanList.size()+1, loan);
        try {
            line=reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here's an input line for reference:

```
John,Doe,8012311213-2-a book,Author,Authorson,1234567890123,another book,Author,Authorson,2345678901234-1-a returned book,Author,Authorson,3456789012345
```

What I'm hoping to get when printing above line:

```
Current Loans:
1. a book by Author Authorson (1234567890123)
2. another book by Author Authorson (2345678901234)

Returned Loans:
1. a returned book by Author Authorson (3456789012345)
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
Current Loans:
1. a book by Author Authorson (1234567890123)
2. a book by Author Authorson (1234567890123)

Returned Loans:
1. a book by Author Authorson (1234567890123)
```

And

```
readLoans();
System.out.println(loanList.get(2).currentLoans.get(1).toString());
System.out.println(loanList.get(2).currentLoans.get(2).toString());
```

returns

```
a returned book by Author Authorson (3456789012345)
a returned book by Author Authorson (3456789012345)
```

Which leads me to believe I actually cannot make instances of my static Book object, but have to make it non-static and try to create instances of the object within the method. If so - how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and actually see what's happening in step-by-step fassion?

Comment: Of course you **cannot** create *instances* of static objects, that's the whole difference between static and non-static ones. Static object belongs to the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it;

```
public static void readLoans(){
    // Reads the bookList and userList.
    readBooks();
    readUsers();
    // Creates a new BufferedReader and tries to read "loans.txt"
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("loans.txt"));
    }
    // Catches exception if "books.txt" does not exist.
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line = null;
    // tries to read the first line and interpret it as a String.
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } 
    // Catches IOexception if any is thrown when trying to read line.
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Loop as long as "line" is not empty, i.e. as long as a Loan is read.
    while (line!=null) {
        // split the String "line" at every RegEx "-"
        String[] splitOut=line.split("-");
        // Create a String from the first index of the first split.
        String user = splitOut[0];
        /* Split the second and third index of the first split and create
         * new Stringarrays from them.*/
        String[] loans = splitOut[1].split(",");
        String[] returns = splitOut[2].split(",");
        User aUser = new User();
        /* Find the user in the userList whose personal ID matches the 
         * String "user" that we created. This is the user that we want to
         * create (a) loan/s and/or (a) returned loan/s for.*/
        for (int i = 1; i < userList.size()+1; i++) {
            if (userList.get(i).getPersonalID().equals(user)) {
                /*Set the variables for the User.*/
                aUser.setFirstname(userList.get(i).getFirstname());
                aUser.setSurname(userList.get(i).getSurname());
                aUser.setPersonalID(userList.get(i).getPersonalID());
                aUser.setTelephone(userList.get(i).getTelephone());
                aUser.setLoans(userList.get(i).getLoans());
                aUser.setReturns(userList.get(i).getReturns());
                // Create an ArrayList for Loans and Returns for every user
                ArrayList<Loan> listOfloans = new ArrayList<Loan>();
                ArrayList<Loan> listOfreturns = new ArrayList<Loan>();
                // if the new user has any loans...
                for (int j = 0; j < aUser.getLoans(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 1; k < bookList.size()+1; k++) {
                        /* ... find the "Book" object with the
                         * corresponding ISBN...*/
                        if (bookList.get(k).getIsbn().equals(loans[j*3])) {
                            // ...then create a new loan object for each...
                            Loan loan = new Loan();
                            // ...and set the variables of each loan...
                            loan.setTitle(bookList.get(k).getTitle());
                            loan.setAuthor_firstname(bookList.get(k).
                                    getAuthor_firstname());
                            loan.setAuthor_surname(bookList.get(k).
                                    getAuthor_surname());
                            try {
                                loan.setIsbn(bookList.get(k).getIsbn());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            loan.setMaxLoan(bookList.get(k).getMaxLoan());
                            loan.setOnLoan(bookList.get(k).getOnLoan());
                            loan.setAvailable(bookList.get(k).
                                    getAvailable());
                            loan.setSignature(loans[j*3+1]);
                            loan.setTimestamp(loans[j*3+2]);
                            /* ...then add each one to the "listOfloans"
                             * ArrayList.*/
                            listOfloans.add(loan);
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* if the "listOfloans" ArrayList is not empty, 
                 * add the loan to loanList with User as Key.*/
                if (!listOfloans.isEmpty()) {
                    loanList.put(aUser, listOfloans);
                }
                // if the new user has any returned loans...
                for (int j = 0; j < aUser.getReturns(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 1; k < bookList.size()+1; k++) {
                        /* ... find the "Book" object with the
                         * corresponding ISBN...*/
                        if(bookList.get(k).getIsbn().equals(returns[j*4])){
                            // ...then create a new loan object for each...
                            Loan loan = new Loan();
                            // ...and set the variables of each loan...
                            loan.setTitle(bookList.get(k).getTitle());
                            loan.setAuthor_firstname(bookList.get(k).
                                    getAuthor_firstname());
                            loan.setAuthor_surname(bookList.get(k).
                                    getAuthor_surname());
                            try {
                                loan.setIsbn(bookList.get(k).getIsbn());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            loan.setMaxLoan(bookList.get(k).getMaxLoan());
                            loan.setOnLoan(bookList.get(k).getOnLoan());
                            loan.setAvailable(bookList.get(k)
                                    .getAvailable());
                            loan.setSignature(returns[j*4+1]);
                            loan.setTimestamp(returns[j*4+2]);
                            loan.setReturndate(returns[j*4+3]);
                            /* ...then add each one to the "listOfreturns"
                             * ArrayList.*/
                            listOfreturns.add(loan);
                        }
                    }
                }
                /* if the "listOfreturns" ArrayList is not empty, 
                 * add the returned loan to returnList with User as Key.*/
                if (!listOfreturns.isEmpty()) {
                    returnList.put(aUser, listOfreturns);   
                }
            }
        }
        // tries to read the next line and interpret it as a String.
        try {
            line=reader.readLine();
        }
        // Catches IOexception if any is thrown when trying to read line.
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // try to close the BufferedReader.
    try {
        reader.close();
    }
    // Catches IOexception if any is thrown when trying to close.
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It was a problem with the instancing of the Book object and with objects and methods being static. I had to rewrite a few of the methods behind the scenes that were major problems. Thanks for all the help! =)

Answer (score 1):

From here, it's hard to understand how you can understand as much as you do, and yet be so confused, at the same time.  I don't mean that to be insulting - just to say that I'm not at all sure I understand where you are.

Create instances by using `new`.  So in your two loops, where you keep overwriting the one static book, instead you need a local variable that you assign a `new` book to and then set the fields on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that your Book is static, the problem is more simply that it's the same object every time you change it during the loop. This does happen because you've declared it as a static field but you are on the wrong track thinking the way you are about it.

Let's simplify the problem and instead of a Book, use this to illustrate:

```
class AnObject {
    int aValue;
}
```

And instead of IO, just loop some times and add it to a list:

```
class PersistenceOfChangesDemo {
    static List<AnObject> theList = new ArrayList<AnObject>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnObject theObject = new AnObject();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            /* reassign the object's value */
            theObject.aValue = i;
            /* adds the same object each time */
            theList.add(theObject);
        }

        /* theList is now of size 3
         * but all its elements refer to the same object (theObject) */
        for(AnObject anObject : theList) {
            /* prints '3' every time
             * because that was the last value assigned */
            System.out.println(anObject.aValue);
            /* prints 'true' every time */
            System.out.println(anObject == theObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is that you need to create a new object each time you want a new one:

```
class PersistenceOfChangesDemo {
    static List<AnObject> theList = new ArrayList<AnObject>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            /* make a new object each time */
            AnObject anObject = new AnObject();

            anObject.aValue = i;
            theList.add(anObject);
        }

        /* theList now has references to 3 different objects */
        for(AnObject anObject : theList) {
            /* prints 1, 2, 3 */
            System.out.println(anObject.aValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Per your comment, make sure you are creating the new instance for each time you put it in to the map:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(splitOut[1]); i++) {
    Book newBook = new Book();

    newBook.setName(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
            (splitOut[1])-1)*4)]);
    newBook.setAuthorFirstname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
            (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+1]);
    newBook.setAuthorSurname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
            (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+2]);
    newBook.setISBN(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
            (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+3]);
    loan.currentLoans.put(i, newBook);
}
```

Comment: Even when creating a new instance of the Book object within every for-loop, I still get the same results. I believe it's because my two for-loops are nested within a while-loop, therefore I keep editing the same instance of the object Book, since it's instanced within the while loop. Therefore a new instance is created with every while. Am I right?

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi If you don't call `new Book` inside the for loop then you aren't creating a new one. If your new code looks like my edit and you *are* creating a new object for each `put` then you might have another problem. In that case I'd suggest debugging with a break point inserted before the while loop. For example, maybe your String split indexes are wrong and you need to see what is actually being stored to each Book.

Answer (score 0):

it's just Reference problem. All three are referring to same object `static book` so represent the same details which are inserted last.

The change is only create new object of `Book()` instead of using same object for different detail.

try below code

```
Loan loan = new Loan();
        loan.user.setFirstName(loan_User[0]);
        loan.user.setSurname(loan_User[1]);
        loan.user.setPersonalID(loan_User[2]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(splitOut[1]); i++) {
            book = new Book();          // added this line
            book.setName(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)]);
            book.setAuthorFirstname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+1]);
            book.setAuthorSurname(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+2]);
            book.setISBN(loan_CurrentLoans[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[1])-1)*4)+3]);
            loan.currentLoans.put(i, book);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(splitOut[3]); i++) {
                book = new Book();           // added this line
            book.setName(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)]);
            book.setAuthorFirstname(loan_Returned[((Integer.parseInt
                    (splitOut[3])-1)*4)+1]);
```

Comment: Even when creating a new instance of the Book object I still get the same results. I believe it's because my two for-loops are nested within a while-loop, therefore I keep editing the same instance of the object Book, since it's instanced within the while loop. Therefore a new instance is created with every while. Am I right?

Comment: Now check the edit in above. Reply if working or not with this change?